# Converting date to a varchar using "like" in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

I need to go through few millions of data searching for a year sent as a parameter to a method. The year comes as a varchar.

This is the query I'm working with

```
  SELECT X,Y
  FROM   A
  WHERE  mch_code = 'KN'
  AND    contract = '15KTN'
  AND    to_char(cre_date, 'YYYY') = year_;
```

cre_ date is of type date and year_ is from type carchar.
when performing this query it take around 25 minutes to process it completely.

Is anyone knows about a different approach to find out the quick execution.

Please help.

This didn't work out.

```
SELECT X,Y
FROM   A
WHERE  mch_code = 'KN'
AND    contract = '15KTN'
AND    cre_date LIKE '%2013';
```

The reason might be 'cre_date' and '%2013' are of different types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your query is slow is that you're applying a function to a column on every row in your table. Let's try it another way:

```
SELECT X,Y
  FROM   A
  WHERE  mch_code = 'KN' AND
         contract = '15KTN' AND
        CRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                      AND TO_DATE('01/01/' || year_, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
```

This eliminates the need to apply a function against every row in the table, and should allow any indexes on CRE_DATE to be used.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an index on (mch_code, contract, cre_date) columns, you can improve performance by doing something like:

```
select x, y
from   a
where  mch_code = 'KN'
and    contract = '15KTN'
and    cre_date >= to_date('01/01/'||year_, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    cre_date <  add_months(to_date('01/01/'||year_, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 12);
```

Even better would be to declare the start of the year as a DATE variable prior to running the sql, eg:

```
v_year_dt := to_date('01/01/'||year_, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

which would make the query:

```
select x, y
from   a
where  mch_code = 'KN'
and    contract = '15KTN'
and    cre_date >= v_year_dt
and    cre_date <  add_months(v_year_dt, 12);
```

If you don't have an index on those three columns, you could create a function based index on (mch_code, contract, to_char(cre_date, 'yyyy')) that should help speed up your query, depending on the percentage of rows you're expecting to select. It may help even more if you added the x and y columns into the index, so that no table access was required at all.

Alternatively, you could think about partitioning the table on cre_date, monthly or yearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) function:

```
SELECT X,Y
  FROM A
 WHERE mch_code = 'KN'
   AND contract = '15KTN'
   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cre_date) = year_;
```

Comment: Hi Sameer.. thanks for the reply... but still I cant see a big performance improvement.... :(

Comment: 1. To increase the performance in this case, you can create functional indexes on the `cre_date` column for year only and get a subsequent performance gain. 2. Or, you can create a normal B-tree index on `cre_date` column and provide a date range criteria to fetch the required results. Which should be faster as well.

Comment: Can you give me an example how an index can be created based on year only using cre_date

Comment: Here's an example: 'CREATE INDEX ix_fnc_creyear ON A(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cre_date));'